# Merging HttpGet methods from multiple controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a ASP.NET Core website that makes requests to a ASP.NET Web API. There are some places in my website controllers where I'm currently doing multiple requests to populate dropdowns and lists, before opening the view:

```
// Populate countryies, states and cities, to populate dropdown lists
var countries = await client.GetAsync("countries");
if (countries.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    viewModel.Countries = await countries.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Country>>();
}

var states = await client.GetAsync("states");
if (states.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    viewModel.States = await states.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<State>>();
}

var cities = await client.GetAsync("cities");
if (cities.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    viewModel.Cities = await cities.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<City>>();
}

var residues = await client.GetAsync("residues");
if (residues.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    viewModel.Residues = await residues.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<SiteResidue>>();
}

return View(viewModel);
```

I have to make those requests separately because in my API there are controllers for each table (CountriesController, StatesController, CitiesController...) and the `HttpGet` methods for those tables are declared in the individual controllers. This seems to be structurally correct, but it makes unoptimal requests as I could make just one to receive all the data at the same time and reduce loading time.

**How should I structure my API controllers so I could turn all those requests in just one?** Should I create a "CountriesStatesCitiesControllers", even though there is no table with that name?

Answer (score 2):

As they are all async calls you can make the calls concurrently and wait for all of them to finish:

```
var countriesTask = client.GetAsync("countries");
var statesTask = client.GetAsync("states");
var citiesTask = client.GetAsync("cities");
var residuesTask = client.GetAsync("residues");

await Task.WhenAll(countriesTask, statesTask, citiesTask, residuesTask);

viewModel.Countries = countriesTask.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Country>>();
viewModel.States = statesTask.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<State>>();
viewModel.Cities = citiesTask.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<City>>();
viewModel.Residues = residuesTask.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<SiteResidue>>();

return View(viewModel);
```

Comment: That's a nicer implementation, but it doesn't solve my problem of making multiple requests.

Comment: Well you could implement a Web API endpoint that returns all of the dropdowns in one object but that seems rather monolithic and not at all RESTful. Don't go down the CountriesStatesCitiesControllers route - what if you then needed streets too? Not that you have to have a controller per table - but a controller per logical entity is a better design pattern than returning everything from one endpoint. If you're worried about performance then cache the results in the web layer.

Comment: I see. I'm new to ASP.NET in general, so more than increasing performance I'm trying to learn to make things in the right way. Thanks for the clarification!